# Upgrading .Net FrameWork on currently built projects may lead to problems?

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, compatibility, .net-framework-version

I've been developing 3 projects under one solution for quite a long time and recently i discovered that my .Net framework is 4.0 while i have an option of "upgrading" to 4.6.
I would like to do so but i'm affraid that since my projects are already built it might cause some Compatibility Issues. So is it safe or is it not recommended due to Compatibility Issues?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.0 is obsolete and you must upgrade to at least 4.5.1 and above. Embrace changes, and don't be afraid of compatibility issues. They are resolved and staying in the past won't help you.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about compatibility issues from the standpoint of a *developer*. Some great stuff was added in the transition from 4.0 to 4.6 but you aren't going to see many, if any, breaking API changes.

The larger compatibility problem comes for your end users as they have to have the .NET 4.6 framework installed. I believe that it ships with Windows 8+ and obviously you can have an installer do it.

If it were me, I'd do the upgrade.

Comment: So what was already wrote in 4.0 won't make the compiler(or the component that checks the .net framework) shout at me if i switch to 4.6?

Comment: @WeinForce I won't guarantee no errors, but I wouldn't expect any, no. Do note that all your libraries/projects need to target the *same* version of .NET.

Comment: say i upgrade and it gives me bunch of errors that i fail to fix(or that will take a lot of time) will I be able to return to the former version so my errors will be gone? Or once they're there it's a total mess?

Comment: @WeinForce Nope, you can switch back right away and it won't care. Changing target frameworks isn't nearly as bad as you think it is.